# Regex pattern match by delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

to get the value of gs from the below query.

**(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|gs=accountinga sdf* |gs=tax*|12|ic='38')**

I have tried with below pattern

**(?<=gs=)(.*)([|])**

But this results **gs=accounting asdf* |gs=tax*|12|**

Desired output should be : **accounting asdf*,tax***

is that possible with change in pattern ?

Comment: You mean you need to get all from `gs=` up to `|` and remove spaces from those values?

Comment: don't need to remove space, just get the  value of gs before relimiter (|)

Answer (score 3):

This regex will match as you want.

```
(?<=gs=)([^|)]*)
```

It will also handle the case where gs is the last clause without including the closing bracket in the group.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 2 solutions, see [their online demo](http://ideone.com/rkcB4I).

One is regex-based:

```
var x = "(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|gs=accountinga sdf* |gs=tax*|12|ic='38')";
var result = Regex.Matches(x, @"(?:^|\|)gs=([^|]*)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

NOTE that the `(?:^|\|)gs=([^|]*)` pattern will only match `gs=` at the string beginning or after `|`, and then `([^|]*)` will capture zero or more chars other than `|` into Group 1 that you will collect later with `Select`. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5e%7c%5c%7c)gs%3d(%5b%5e%7c%5d*)&i=(2%7c3%7c4%7c5%7c6%7c7%7c8%7c9%7c10%7c11%7cgs%3daccountinga+sdf*+%7cgs%3dtax*%7c12%7cic%3d%2738%27)).

Or a non-regex based, just split with `|`, check if the item starts with `gs=`, and then split with `=` to get the last part:

```
var res2 = x.Split('|')
        .Where(p => p.StartsWith("gs="))
        .Select(n => n.Split('=').LastOrDefault())
        .ToList();
    foreach (var t in res2)
        Console.WriteLine(t);
```